# Is it possible to scale size (123px 123px) in LESS

Tags: css, less

Using 'less' I know you can scale a height or width value using the **calc** function like so.

```
@height: 500px;
@heightAdj: calc(@height * 1.5px);
```

Is it possible to scale a size value in the same way? I was thinking something that looks like this :

```
@imgSize: 500px 333px;
@imgSizeAdj: calc(@imgSize * (1.5px));
```

Is there something out there that can do this on '123px 123px' style size definitions?

Comment: Just use a height variable and a width variable and scale them up, you cant calc two values in css/less

Comment: The above comment seem correct, why would you need to calc a variable, when you can just set a new value whenever you want, and then recompile the `less` file?

Comment: First of all `calc` is totally redundant there - it's a *browser/CSS* not *Less* function (actually there it's looking nearly like a mistake even if it produce no errors). Second, `1px * 2px` looks like you're calculating an area, i.e. `2px²` (and even if it produces the same `px` result, you'd really better to use normal *scale*: `1px * 2` instead). Aside of that see [less-plugin-lists](https://github.com/seven-phases-max/less-plugin-lists/blob/master/docs/va.md#vector-arithmetic).